# Compilation errors - RadeonRays API based application?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

this is more of a generic question !

**Some info:**

First of all i am not an experienced programmer.
I am trying to create a simple renderer based on RadeonRays ([Radeon Rays](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/RadeonRays_SDK))
I was able to install all required packs - CMake, Python etc...
However in the github page it says that it does require Visual Studio 2015 and i am having 2017.

I created successfully a solution for VS 2017 like this ( NO ERRORS ):

**cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"**

Then i compiled the project successfully ( NO ERRORS ) !

**The Problem:**

I created a new project and included the radeon rays library. All seems ok and got no errors. However i got some compiler errors when i try to compile my project ( visible in the image below ). The errors are all related to a single header file.

As i am not experienced programmer, only option i have, is to ask if one can say if this is because i am trying to use VS2017 instead of VS2015.

**I am not allowed to install VS2015, that's why i am looking for some professional opinion if this might be related to VS version, cause i am getting only compilation errors !
Thanks !**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the problem and solution.
I simply had to define WIN32 or to include the windows.h file in the new project.